# Web Crawler blocked on email link

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I'm making a web crawler in Java using jsoup (using this [tutorial](http://www.programcreek.com/2012/12/how-to-make-a-web-crawler-using-java/)).

The problem I face is that the crawler takes into the Element loop each link, some of them being email address. So when I try to use `Jsoup.connect(URL)` on an email address, I get an error telling me only to use http or https requests.

How can I stop my program to do the recursion when getting an email address link?

Here is the Main code :

```
public class Main {

public static DB db = new DB();

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, IOException{
    db.runSql2("TRUNCATE Record;");
    processPage("http://www.mit.edu");
}

public static void processPage(String URL) throws SQLException,IOException{
    String sql = "select * from Record where URL = '" +URL+"'";
    ResultSet rs = db.runSql(sql);
    if(rs.next()){

    } else {
        sql = "INSERT INTO  `Crawler`.`Record` " + "(`URL`) VALUES " + "(?);";
        PreparedStatement stmt = db.conn.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        stmt.setString(1,URL);
        stmt.execute();

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();

        if(doc.text().contains("research")){
            System.out.println(URL);
        }

        Elements questions = doc.select("a[href]");
        for(Element link:questions){
            if(link.attr("href").contains("mit.edu")){
                System.out.println(link.attr("abs:href"));
                processPage(link.attr("abs:href"));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already fairly close, and this feels like an assignment so I'm just going to give you a nudge, not the complete answer.

You're checking to see if it's an `mit.edu` page here:

```
if(link.attr("href").contains("mit.edu")){
                System.out.println(link.attr("abs:href"));
                processPage(link.attr("abs:href"));
            }
```

Now, you need an additional condition to look for things that only start with `http` or `https`. [Check out](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)) the `String.startsWith()` method and use that to check the value of the hyperlink before you call `processPage`.

Comment: Thank you ! I added a startswith http condition and it works. I also added a try catch on the processPage recursive call because i got some image links that Jsoup can't parse into html. I don't really know how to stop it either ^^ PS : It wasn't an assignment i just want to learn

Answer (score 2):

You can just check if the link is a URL by looking if it starts with `http`. Because you've got an absolute URL (using `abs:href`), and it starts with http, it could only be a http or a https URL (and not a link to an email address, or an FTP site, of some other junk you don't want.)

For example, update your for loop to this:

```
for (Element link : questions) {
    String href = link.attr("abs:href");
    if (href.contains("mit.edu") && href.startsWith("http")) {
        System.out.println(href);
        processPage(href);
    }
}
```

Also, I would be inclined to put a try/catch around each `processPage` call so that if you get one error fetching a page (like a network timeout or whatever), your whole application doesn't crash.

Answer (score 1):

You need to test if `!link.attr("abs:href").startsWith("mailto:")`.